# How to add custom properties on the Request object in Express + TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, authentication

I am trying to add a user object as a custom property in the Request object of Express, but I got the following error:

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'
```

This is my code in a middleware function:

```
  // Authenticate person/user through the database.
  const person = new Person(username, password);
  const user = await authenticate(person); // ORM => read DB 
  if (!user) {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json({ message: "Invalid Authentication Credentials" });
  }

  // attach user to request object
  req.user = user; // <= HERE is my problem
  next();
```

How I can add this custom property to the request?

Comment: Please show more code context so we can see what this code is located inside of.  And, if this is a TypeScript-specific error, then you will have to do some TypeScript stuff to be allowed to add a custom property to an object that only has certain properties as far as TypeScript is concerned.  This is the extra work involved when using a typed system.  See this [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/extend-express-request-object-typescript/) for more info.

Comment: Hey, @jfriend00 thanks for your comment. I will read that article.

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard way to do this is by extending the `Response` interface exported by Express and declaring your Data as being part of the `Locals` generic type.

In `@types/express/index.d.ts` @ line 127:

```
export interface Response<ResBody = any, Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>>
        extends core.Response<ResBody, Locals> {}
```

You can therefore create a Type that will be used in lieu of the default value for the `Locals` generic like so:

```
import type { Response, Request, NextFunction } from 'express';
import type { User } from './models'; // Or wherever it is, obviously.
type MyLocals = { user?: User; };
type MyResponse = Response<any, MyLocals>

// Using the `MyResponse` type is as simple as setting the type of `res` to be `MyResponse`, e.g.:

async function doSomeWork (req: Request, res: MyResponse, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> {
  console.log(res.locals.user); // undefined | User
}
```

There are some other ways to achieve this, as well, but this is what I have always done when using Typescript + Express.